# How to use conditional formatting to complete task

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of dates in one spreadsheet. I want to bold the dates that match dates in another spreadsheet. I know I need to use conditional formatting but not sure how to.I can use "Format only cells that contain".... but it would take forever since I am checking almost 30 dates in the other spreadsheet. I would have to create 30 rules. Is there a quicker way to do this in one rule?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please share us with a simple sample?

Here, I suggest you use formula to have a check.

[image]

On my sample, I use `=MATCH(A2,$I$2:$I$21,0)` to check whether the dates of Date1 match dates of Date2.

If so, I will apply the conditional formatig to the results.